# Validate input from keyboard and displayed

Tags: c++, c, validation

I need to validate the input from keyboard if the program request a leter and the user put a number do not show at screen. I am using **linux**

Comment: Write a program using `getchar()` and `isalpha()`

Comment: @chqrlie:  The `getchar()` function echoes to the the terminal.

Comment: thank you, I was thinking getch() but it's from conio

Answer (score -1):

Read it to char and then you can use function from `<ctype.h>`: `isdigit()` or `isalpha()`